# How do I get the value of checkboxes in jquery having common names.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following series of checkboxes coming from the datatables in the form like below:

```
<input id="list-chk_1"  type="checkbox" /> 
<input id="list-chk_2"  type="checkbox" /> 
<input id="list-chk_3"  type="checkbox" />
```

How can I separate that id from list-chk. Do I have to include data-id parameter?

Comment: what you actually want to do can you explain more??

Comment: Use different class name to seperate them

Comment: @divakar..My question is how can i use these id say 1,2,3 for manipulations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my understanding, Try that

```
$('input[id^="list-chk"]').click(function(){
    $(this).attr("id"); //Getting click control ID
    $(this).val(); //Getting Value
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split if you know the ID always has that format.

```js
var ins = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < ins.length; i++) {
  document.write(ins[i].id.split('_')[1]);
}

// jQuery
$('input').each(function() {
   $('body').append(this.id.split('_')[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="list-chk_1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="list-chk_2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="list-chk_3" type="checkbox" />
```

Split will make an array from the given string, splitting it where you tell it to.

```
"list-chk_1".split('_') // results in ["list-chk", "1"]
```

Other methods could be using `var idnr = this.id.replace('list-chk_', '');`